# Low degree factors of $f_1(x)^n+f_2(x)^n-f_3(x)^n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Let $f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x)$ be coprime polynomials with integer coefficients.

Let $g(x)$ be a factor of $f_1(x)^n+f_2(x)^n-f_3(x)^n$.

We are interested when the degree of $g(x)$ can be low.

One possibility is when $f_1(x)+f_2(x)=f_3(x)$.

Assume $\pm f_1(x) \pm f_2(x) \ne f_3(x)$.

> Q1 is it possible $\deg g(x) \le n-2$?

Comment: If you take $f_1,f_2,f_3$ arbitrary polynomials with $f_1(0)=f_3(0)=1$ and $f_2(0)=0$, then $f_1(x)^n+f_2(x)^n-f_3(x)^n$ is divisible by $x$.

Comment: @abx Many thanks! Can you squeeze one more factor besides one linear?

Comment: The same is of course true for any arbitrary divisor $g$ of $f_2$, as long as $f_1\equiv f_3$ mod $g$; one should first identify all trivial cases like this to make this an interesting question.